# When is data really deleted in Clickhouse with the new `DELETE` query

Tags: clickhouse

Clickhouse recently released the new `DELETE` query, that allows you to quickly mark data as deleted (https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/delete/).
The actual data deletion is done in the background afterwards, as is written in the docs.

My question is, is there some indication to when data would be deleted?
Or is there a way to make sure it gets deleted?
I'm asking for GDPR compliance purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to CH support on slack:
If using the DELETE query, the only way to make sure data is deleted is to use the `OPTIMIZE FINAL` query.
This would trigger a merge and the deleted data won't be included in the outcome

Comment: Then what is the actual difference between `ALTER TABLE ... DELETE` and `DELETE`?

Comment: `DELETE` simply marks the data as deleted, but actual data deletion from the disk is done in the next merge.

Comment: I see, it is not returned in queries then.

Comment: Yes. It's not returned in queries

Answer (score 1):

For GDRP better use

`ALTER TABLE ... DELETE WHERE ...`

and poll
`SELECT * FROM system.muations WHERE is_done=0`

when mutation complete (is_done=1), that mean data deleted physically

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ClickHouse cluster, you can query all 'system.mutations' records on all nodes with the following query. Ensure to replace the placeholder 'default' with your actual cluster name:

```
SELECT mutation_id,*
FROM clusterAllReplicas('default',system.mutations)
FORMAT Vertical;
```